# Alternating harmonic series rearrangement

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Rearrange $\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n$ to converge to $1$

I am unable to find it's rearrangement.
Also Pringshiem method that gives positive to negative terms is coming to be irrational.

Comment: If you are looking an explicit formula, don't. If you want a rearrangement, it's simple: add positive terms until you are above 1, then add negative terms until you are below 1, then positive again and so on.

Comment: For every odd number $j$, the terms with $n=j\cdot2^k$ sum to zero, and every term appears in exactly one of these subsequences. It should be possible to use that to make the rearranged series converge to $0$ (e.g. by arranging the terms according to $j$ and $k$ and going along the diagonals, but I haven't thought that through). If so, perhaps you could somehow use that to make it converge to $1$ instead.